# Returning a tag name with Hpple HTML Parser?

Tags: iphone, regex, parsing, xpath, hpple

How do i grab the **URL_TO_GRAB**, with Hpple/Xpath for iPhone? Do i need to use some regex?

```
<div class="content">
  <a href="URL_TO_GRAB"> Link </a>
</div>
```

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it like this,

```
NSArray * elements = [doc search:@"//a"];
for ( TFHppleElement * element in elements ) {
    NSString * URLString = [[element attributes] objectForKey:@"href"];
    NSLog(@"%@", URLString);
}
```

This matches all anchor links and prints their urls.